# how to run laragon virtual host on port 82

Tags: laragon

i have checked auto virtual hosts on my laragon, this virtual host was created, but since i am running on port 82 and not the default port 80 i cannot access

`sample.dev:82`

nor

`localhost:82/sample.dev`

i have this in my hosts file

`127.0.0.1      sample.dev           #laragon magic!`

i even tried  putting the port number after the 127.0.0.1:80

`127.0.0.1:82      sample.dev           #laragon magic!`

and

`127.0.0.1      sample.dev:82           #laragon magic!`

neither is working, how do i access sample.dev on my web browser

```
<VirtualHost *:82> 
DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/sample/public/"
ServerName sample.dev
ServerAlias *.sample.dev
<Directory "C:/laragon/www/sample/public/">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution 
change
`{name}.dev` to `{name}.test` in menu>preferences>general
then change the port number in menu>preferences>services and port